# How to change data in different Ionic pages?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have event listener which fires when user logs in:

```
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
this.events.subscribe('user:login', () => {
    this.nav.push(HomePage)
    this.nav.setRoot(HomePage)
})
```

In `HomePage` page I have field:

```
<ion-title style="text-align: center" [(ngModel)]="username"></ion-title>
```

So I'm wondering how could I update `HomePage` from `app.component.ts` to set up username?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NavParams` to send data across pages in ionic.

`` this.nav.push(HomePage, {user: 'value`}) ``

Then in `HomePage`

```
import { NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
class HomePage {
  constructor(private navParams: NavParams) {
     this.user = navParams.get('user');
  }
}
```

Check out [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavParams/)